# How to avoid glares in Unity directional light?

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject, directional-light

I have a quad with a texture filled in on top a camera. When I added directional light, it shows a glare in the center. Earlier, I had it right, but now not sure why it comes. Below is my unity camera game with center glare & scene

[image: Unity glare on directional light]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a point light to me. Try to enable 3d view and move on the z Axis. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have `DrawHalo` on the `DirectionalLight` enabled. Otherwise you might need to adjust the specular/metallic settings on your quads material.

Comment: Unchecking spectacular highlights work but what s the deal with Draw halo? It does not seem to showing any changes